# Excel VB Search Macro with True/False

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to reconcile the payments made to a bank account through automatic payments. Initially this was easy, a simple ‘cntrl+f’ would allow me to find all I needed. However as the list has grown this has become time consuming. I have run a macro doing what I normally do and here are the results:

```
    Sub Findname()
'
' Findname Macro
'
'
    Sheets("9 Month AP").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BUTLAND"
    Sheets("Bank Statements").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="BUTLAND", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("B136").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "47.45"
    Sheets("9 Month AP").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

In this example what I would like to do is take the information out of A1:”9 Month AP”. In this case it is the person’s name “BUTLAND”, find the data (name) in sheet “Bank Statements” and take the information in the B (the amount they paid $47.45) column (in this example B136) and paste it into sheet “9 Month Ap”.
The question I have is twofold. I don’t think this macro is efficient at all, is this the best way to write it? Secondly, how can I loop it so that it steps down the sheet ie; in this example it has taken A1, the next step A2, A3 and so on? At each step pasting into the C column?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Question may be off-topic, there are LOTS of examples of looping/iterating over a range of cells, etc. here on SO.

Comment: I have deleted the vb.net tag because there is nothing in the question that relates to vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

As David Zemens said, it's pretty straight forward to iterate through a range:

```
    Sub test()

    DoSomethingByCellValue "BUTLAND", "47.5", Range("A1:A200")

    End Sub


    Sub DoSomethingByCellValue(ByVal searchVal As Variant, ByVal insertVal As Variant, _
ByRef xlrange As Excel.Range)

    'allocate for a range for use in the loop
    Dim xlcell As Excel.Range

    'loop through each cell in the range
    For Each xlcell In xlrange
        'if it equals the search term
        If xlcell.Value = searchVal Then
            'do something... e.g.
            xlcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = insertVal
            'or xlcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = xlcell.Offset(0, 1).Value + insertVal
        End If
    Next xlcell

End Sub
```

If you want to use the in-built search function, you will need to return an iterable or use the .FindNext feature. The following code, taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx), maybe useful for you.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```